# Is there any way to sign the document in our own application without going to DocuSign website?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Right now I can't find a way to have the user to sign the document using DocuSign in our own application. What I need to do:

- Have the user sign the document in our own application.
- Get the signature with an API from DocuSign
  Any help will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called "embedded signing" and is one of the most popular use-cases with the DocuSign eSign API.

Here is the Node.js code example to do this:

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/embeddedSigning.js

Comment: Yes, but I see that we're still going out of our website/app and visit the DocuSign web to complete the signing. What if I wanted to sign the document inside my app without opening a browser or a new tab?

Comment: the only option for that is using a product called DocuSign Appliance, which means you'll have to first set up servers to do all the digital signature related activities on your premise. To use DocuSign cloud - you have to use the web.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/dsa-api/how-to/esign-existing-new-pdfs/